# Question on law firm application

Tags: meaning

> “We pride ourselves on being law, less ordinary. How are you less ordinary?”

I do not understand how the first sentence makes sense. Anyone care to explain? (Assuming it is not a typo.)

Comment: I would feel tempted to respond, "Everybody's normal -- till you get to know them".

Comment: What is the source? Can provide more context?

Comment: Is there a definite article missing there?

Answer (score 3):

My guess is they've taken a bit of poetic license in order to create a play on the phrase "a life less ordinary".

The motto is suggesting that either "we're a *special* law firm" (*less ordinary*) or, stronger, "we're a law firm lacking *any* of the usual characteristics" (literally "less" -- meaning "without" -- ordinary). In either case, the idea is they're only interested in extra-ordinary employees.

Anyway, the pun is cute, but makes the sentence a bit obtuse (in particular, the synecdoche of "law" for "law firm", in order to, presumably, keep the cadence of the original "life less ordinary"; I can't imagine they actually have the hubris to assert "we ARE the law").  I'm also guessing they didn't see the alternative, more ironic pun their phrasing could suggest: "lawless ordinary".

Comment: Then again, would you want to live a lifeless ordinary? :)

On point: less ordinary/more special? I agree the statement is awkward. Even if "it makes you think", it appears (to me) to imply the stigma of less = not as good, and then if ordinary is "okay", this is "not as good as" "okay".